# SQL 2008 offset rows

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a select statement like this

```
select t.time, t.temperature, t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t
```

I want to add a offset temperature column, such that :

```
select t.time, t.temperature, t.temperature(t.time-1/24.0) as temperaturem1, t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t
```

As of 2012 I can see the offset function may be usable for this purpose. However, how would you recommend to solve this problem in SQL 2008R2?

I may add that the statement should be done in the least computational heavy method possible. This is due to the fact that `dbo.weatherdata` is large. Hence, if I would be able to avoid joins that would be preferable.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you could join to itself with that condition and then get temperature values from both copies of the table in the join.

Comment: @shree.pat18 I would add that this select statement is timeconsuming so I would like to do this with minimum computational effort.

Comment: what exactly do you expect the text `t.temperature(t.time-1/24.0)` to mean? Apparently `t.temperature` is a column yet you use it as a function. and what exactly is `t.time-1/24.0` supposed to mean?

Comment: @RemusRusanu it is just a figure of expression. I am basically interested in doing an offset such that I can retrieve the value from the previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reading every hour, you can use the `lag()` function:

```
select t.time, t.temperature,
       lag(t.temperature) over (order by temperature) as temperaturem1,
       t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t;
```

This pulls the `temperature` from the *previous* row, where *previous* is defined by the `order by` clause.

EDIT:

If you have irregular readings or for SQL Server 2008, then I think you need to use a join.  The natural way to write this would be:

```
select t.time, t.temperature, tprev.temperature as temperaturem1,
       t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t left outer join
     dob.weatherdata tprev
     on tprev.time = t.time - 1/24.0;
```

However, this probably would not work, because the floating point arithmetic is not exact.  You could try something like:

```
select t.time, t.temperature, tprev.temperature as temperaturem1,
       t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t left outer join
     dob.weatherdata tprev
     on tprev.time > t.time - (1/24.0 + 0.001) and
        tprev.time < t.time + (1/24.0 + 0.001) ;
```

Actually, I think I like `cross apply` better:

```
select t.time, t.temperature, tprev.temperature as temperaturem1,
       t.wind
from dbo.weatherdata t cross apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      dob.weatherdata tprev
      order by abs(datediff(second, tprev.time, dateadd(second, -3600, t.time)))
     ) tprev;
```

Comment: @shree.pat18 . . . That is interesting.  I just missed the reference to 2008 after the mention of 2012.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for your input! 
What would you say would require the least computational burden?

Comment: Yeah that's why I thought I should point it out. But +1 for a comprehensive answer!

Comment: @SteewDK . . . If you want efficiency, you might want to ask another question and provide more information on the table layout and sample data.  It is hard to say what the most efficient method is without such information.  In general, join on an equality condition would be the most efficient, but I don't know if that is possible.